# how to mix use of optional parameter and parameter with default value in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I would like to have a function that take optional parameter and parameter with default value something like following, but how can I call the function?

```
function func(a = '', b?: string, d = false) {
  if (b) {
    console.log(b)
  }
  console.log(a)
  console.log(d)
}
//how to call?
func() //a, false
func({ 'c': '2' }) //2, a, false
func({'a': 'string', 'c': '2', 'd': true}) // 2, string, true
```

Comment: The code you have wouldn't work because the first argument must be a string, and you've passed in an object. Plus I don't see how `{c:'2'}` could ever produce `2, a, false`.

Comment: yes, my code wont work, since I do not know how to call the function or right way to create a function with optional parameter and parameter with default value

Comment: I would go each function call step-by-step, look at the first call you are making to `func()` this will only return `false` as there's no string, and so `a param` is not returned. then first the last two, you have to look into the *param optional* and the way you are *ordering the arguments* in the function call. those two have to match and need to be in sync.

Answer (score 1):

The second two calls assume that you have an options argument. I.e. an object collecting various options but your function is defined to only accept a list of arguments. If you want to maintain the call format you would need to change the definition, something along the lines of this:

```
function func(options?: { a?: string, b?: string, c?: string, d?: boolean })
{
  // Combines default values with inputs
  const { a, b, c, d } = { a: '', d: false, ...options }

  if (b) {
    console.log(b)
  }
  console.log(a)
  console.log(d)
}
```

Comment: what if I would like to use the format o func?, how should I call it?

Comment: @jacobcan118: You can't, unless you adhere to the exact positions of the arguments. E.g. you cannot just call the function and only provide `d`, you would need to provide all the other arguments before `d` as well. You can only leave off arguments from the right side.